# Keybind that binds to every key in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, key-bindings

I am creating an interactive game with Python, and I am trying to make an introduction with the instruction "Press any key to continue." I am having some difficulty with binding all the keys to a single action.

I have tried binding to `'<Any>'`, but it displays an error message.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

root = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500)

def testing():
    print("Hello World!")

root.bind_all('<Any>', testing)

root.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

As mentioned before, the `'<Any>'` keybind results in an error message reading: `tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Any"`. Is there a simple way to bind every key to an action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `<Key>` it will capture any keyboard event and print "Hello". And don't forget to specify `event` or `event=None` parameter in `testing()` .

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

root = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500)

def testing(event):
    print("Hello!")

def countdown(count, label):
    label['text'] = count
    if count > -1:
        root.after(1000, countdown, count-1, label)
    elif count == 0:
        label['text'] = 'Time Expired'
    elif count < 0:
        label.destroy()

root.bind_all('<Key>', testing)

root.pack()
root.mainloop()
```