# Check if a specific key is pressed in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I've been trying to use tkinter to check if a specific key is pressed, but I haven't found anything, so I'm sarting to wonder if it's impossible. So, I'm checking if anyone knows a way to do it. By the way, I don't want to use the listener thing from pynput because it can't run simultaneously with tkinter.

If you know a way to do it and you can do in a beginner friendly way, I would appricate it alot, but if you can't, post is anyway, I'm thankfull for everyting :)

My finished script (this was what i wanted to do):

```py
import tkinter
import pyautogui

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x500")

def sum():
    label = tkinter.Label(root, text="yes")
    label.place(x=500, y=250)

def fun(event):
    if event.keysym=='b':
        pyautogui.moveTo(x=500, y=500)

root.bind("<Key>", fun)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried binding a key listener to the root window?

Comment: [Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32289245/13629335)

Comment: [Or this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55603461/13629335)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bind `KeyRelease` or `Key` to a function. The function will be called with an argument when the event occurs. The argument will contain all the information about the event.

Sample output:

```
<KeyPress event state=Mod1|Mod3 keysym=d keycode=68 char='d' x=85 y=111>
```

now to get the key use `event.keysym`

sample program:

```py
from tkinter import *

def fun(event):
    print(event.keysym, event.keysym=='a')
    print(event)

root = Tk()

root.bind("<KeyRelease>", fun)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the keyboard library to check if any keyboard input is incoming.
Here is some example code:

```
import keyboard

# Check if b was pressed
if keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
    print('b Key was pressed')
```

Comment: I get the error <No module named 'keyboard'> and since I'm a very beginner I have no clue of what that means.

Comment: It means you whave to go to the command prompt and do the command: pip install keyboard