# Is there a way to read keypresses from the Enter key?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been fooling around in python (v3.9.10) and I have found no way to read keypresses from the enter key and have tkinter do something with that keypress. I am trying to make a dumb little program to show some numbers on my screen for school and want to be able to do it quickly. this is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *



#DEFS
def submit():
    submitted=entrybox.get()
    display.config(text=submitted)

app=Tk()

entrybox=Entry(width=10)

entrybox.place(x=10,y=10)

#display label
display=Label(text=' ')
display.place(x=50,y=50)
display.config(font='Arial 72')

#submit button
subbutton=Button(text='SUBMIT',command=submit)
subbutton.place(x=70,y=10)
```

(Sorry if my code looks really bad I am quite new to python and everything it has to offer)
(I am also sorry for sounding repetitive and/or dumb. Forums such as this aren't familiar to me either)

is there any way to read key presses from the enter key while allowing the rest of my tkinter stuff to run as intended? thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a specific key is pressed in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66815257/check-if-a-specific-key-is-pressed-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to bind and handle events

Use [`bind(sequence, func)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events) method on your widget (like `Button` or even the root app `Tk`).

The parameter `sequence` is one of the [predefined events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289175/list-of-all-tkinter-events), a string name for keys, mouse-events, etc.
The parameter `func` is a callback or handler function, given by name only (without parentheses or arguments), which must have one positional parameter for `Event`.

#### Demo

See this minimal example:

```
from tkinter import *

def callback(event):
    print(event)


def quit():   # did we miss something ?
    print("Escape was pressed. Quitting.. Bye!")
    exit()

app = Tk()
app.bind('<Return>', callback)  # on keypress of Enter or Return key
app.bind('<Enter>', callback)  # on mouse-pointer entering the widget - here the app's root window (not confuse with Enter key of keyboard)
app.bind('<Escape>', quit)  # on keypress of Escape key

app.mainloop()  # to start the main loop listening for events
```

Prints after following keys pressed:

1. Enter key was pressed
2. Escape key was pressed

```
<KeyPress event keysym=Return keycode=36 char='\r' x=-583 y=-309>
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: quit() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Note:

1. The Enter key was caught and bound callback/handler function (`callback`) invoked which prints the passed `event`.
2. The Escape key was caught and bound callback/handler function (`quit`) invoked. But since it hasn't the required parameter (like `event`) the invocation failed with a `TypeError`.

When adding the parameter `def quit(event):` it succeeds:

```
<Enter event focus=True x=6 y=188>
<Enter event focus=True x=182 y=45>
<KeyPress event keysym=Return keycode=36 char='\r' x=-583 y=-309>
<Enter event state=Button1 focus=True x=123 y=68>
Escape was pressed. Quitting.. Bye!
```

Note:

1. The `<Enter>` event is when the mouse-pointer enters the (visible) widget frame, here of the application's root window.
2. The `<Escape>` event exits the application

#### Further reading

RealPython: [Python GUI Programming With Tkinter](https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/) is a rich tutorial to learn more, especially on [Using `.bind()`](https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/#using-bind).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.bind()` to do this like so:

```
app.bind('<Return>', function)
```

This will call `function` when enter is pressed. `'<return>'` denotes the return or enter key, and it calls `function` when the event of a return keypress occurs.

You could add it to your code like so:

```
from tkinter import *

def submit():
    submitted=entrybox.get()
    display.config(text=submitted)

app=Tk()

entrybox=Entry(width=10)

entrybox.place(x=10,y=10)

#display label
display=Label(text=' ')
display.place(x=50,y=50)
display.config(font='Arial 72')

#submit button
subbutton=Button(text='SUBMIT',command=submit)
subbutton.place(x=70,y=10)

app.bind('<Return>', lambda x: submit())
app.mainloop()
```

This will do what you are looking for...

Comment: @hc_dev fair point, I partially explain how it worked originally, but I add a little more detail as well. As for the theory so to speak about Tk documentation, I will leave that up to someone else, or for the OP to read if it is needed.

Comment: Well explained ️ For further reading I added some researched links to my answer

Comment: this helps a ton! thanks!

Comment: Sure thing Jack!